# What is a good program, with PostScript output (for LaTeX), to make circuit diagrams?

Tags: windows-xp, diagrams, postscript, schematic

I just found out to my dismay that Visio 2007 does *not* include the ability to output drawings in EPS/PS formats, which makes it unsuitable for my uses.

I wish to create various circuit digrams (including some texts for resistor values, voltage sources, etc...) with most electronic components (resistors, logic gates).  Visio was a great tool for this, but I need to include these in lab reports which I am typesetting with LaTeX.

The recommended format to include images in LaTeX is PostScript, so the fonts can be properly substituted, and the drawings scale properly.

So my question:

**Is there a Windows program which will allow me to create circuit diagrams, add various labels, and export it to PostScript format?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dia](http://dia-installer.de/index_en.html), an open source alternative to Visio, supports exporting to the EPS format.

[image]

It has libraries for circuit diagrams too.

Answer (score 2):

I simply installed a PostScript printer attached to FILE:. That way you get export functionality to PostScript for free in every application that can print.

You lack EPS then, though as the bounding box comment is missing.

Furthermore, LaTeX can include PDF files without problems (when using `pdflatex`, at least).